# Kernel and image of composition of maps.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $f:V \to V, g:V\to V$ be linear and bijective maps such that $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_V$ (identity mapping). Show that:

a) $\ker(f) = \ker(f\circ g)$.

b) $\operatorname{Im}(g) = \operatorname{Im}(g \circ f)$

I'm not sure where to start and what strategy to use. Please help to guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both $f$ and $f \circ g$ are linear bijective maps (composition of linear maps is linear) so they have trivial kernel. This shows a).

For b), the right inverse of a linear bijective map (isomorphism in the category of vector spaces) is also its left inverse. So $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_V$. So $g$ and $g \circ f$ are both linear bijective maps, which shows that both their images is whole $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to show that two things are equal one way to do it is show that they are contained in on another, for example in your case show that $\ker(f)\subseteq \ker(f\circ g)$ and $\ker(f\circ g)\subseteq \ker(f)$.  Also in you case it is really easy to see what are the kernel of these maps since you know $f\circ g =\operatorname{id}_V$, so the kernel must be trivial.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if that seems dumb, but how do you go from bijection to the fact that the kernel is trivial?

Comment: No problem, By definition of bijection you have that the function is injective and since you are working with a linear map that is equivalent to a trivial kernel.